# How do I make it so my phtml only appears on the shipping part of the checkout page and no where else?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I've got an extension that adds a OAuth login to the checkout page, I only want it to appear on the shipping part of the checkout page and no where else:

want:

[image]

Don't want:

[image]

checkout_index_index:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>PixelPin Connect</title>
        <css src="Pixelpin_Connect::pixelpin_connect/css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Pixelpin\Connect\Block\Pixelpin\Account" name="pixelpin_connect_pixelpin_account" template="Pixelpin_Connect::account.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Pixelpin\Connect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="pixelpin_connect_account_pixelpin_button" template="Pixelpin_Connect::button.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

checkout.phtml:

```
<div class="checkout-container">
    <div class="opc-wrapper">
       <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
          <div class="pixelpin-connect-checkout">
                <div class="<?php echo $this->_getColSet(); ?>">
                <!--<?php if (!$block->isLoggedIn()): ?>-->
                   <?php if($this->_pixelpinEnabled()): ?>
                         <div class="<?php echo $this->_getCol(); ?> inchoo-socialconnect-checkout-pixelpin">
                            <div class="step-title" data-role="title"><?php echo __('Pixelpin Connect') ?></div>
                             <p><?php echo __('You can continue with checkout using your <strong>Pixelpin</strong> account.') ?></p>
                             <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('pixelpin_connect_login_checkout_button');?>
                         </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 <!--<?php endif; ?>-->
                </div>
           </div>
       </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```